# Component list for SXA

Tags: sxa

I've been tasked with coming up with a user manual that shows the current components we have on sitecore 8 and compares them to the components available for sitecore 9 sxa.

However I haven't been given a sitecore 9 environment to test on so have to make this document based purely off internet research.

I've had a look around but can't find anything, is there a comprehensive list of SXA components with descriptions and pictures anywhere? Even the official SXA documentation doesn't seem to have this.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the full list of renderings available for SXA 1.8:

- Accordion
- Carousel
- Flip
- Tabs
- Snippet
- Language Selector
- Site Selector
- Facebook Comments
- Livefyre
- Event Calendar
- Event List
- WFFM Wrapper
- Sitecore Forms Wrapper
- MVC Form
- Map
- File List
- Flash
- Gallery
- Image
- Image (Reusable)
- Media Link
- Playlist
- Video
- Archive
- Breadcrumb
- Link
- Link List
- Navigation
- Field Editor
- Page Content
- Page List
- Pagination
- Plain HTML
- Plain HTML (Reusable)
- Promo
- Rich Text
- Rich Text (Reusable)
- Title
- Container
- Divider
- Edit Mode Panel
- IFrame
- Splitter (Columns)
- Splitter (Rows)
- Toggle
- Filter (Checklist)
- Filter (Date)
- Filter (Dropdown)
- Filter (Managed Range)
- Filter (Radius)
- Filter (Range Slider)
- Filter (Slider)
- Load More
- Location Finder
- Page Selector
- Page Size
- Results Count
- Results Variant Selector
- Search Box
- Search Results
- Sort Results
- Login
- Logout
- Social Login Wrapper
- AddThis
- Feed
- Social Media share
- Tag Cloud
- Tag List

You can read more about them in Sitecore documentation:

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-sxa-renderings-and-rendering-variants.html

Comment: Thanks for this list and the link, I'll do some research into them