# Is it possible to extract a list of all Custom Controls

Tags: presentation

We have an inherited Sitecore 8.2 instance. I am very new to Sitecore so I apologize if my terminology is wrong!

While our team has completed some custom development since taking over the site, I now need to find a way to extract a list of all custom controls within the site so we have a complete catalog.
I essentially need to take stock of what we have now and if any controls are no longer being used (and indeed if we have inadvertently ended up with virtually identical controls).

Is this possible?

If so, is it also possible this extract can include details of where or if the controls are actually used?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by custom controls, could you please add screenshots?

Comment: No worries, you can add some images so it would be easy.

Comment: Sorry, being so new i know i'm using the wrong terminology, which i know can make it hard for others to help so I really appreciate you responding!

I'm referring to custom components, 'things' that are rendered on pages.  We are looking at what is offered in the SXA Toolbox for SiteCore 10.1 and trying to determine if we have developed some components that would become redundant in an upgrade (as the same functionality would be available out of the box). Does that make sense?

I will ask a colleague of mine to get screen shots as requested, but it won't be until after the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

SXA provide some OOTB components and you can find list here:

[image]
https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-sxa-renderings-and-rendering-variants.html

[Component list for SXA](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18694/component-list-for-sxa)

And if you want to check which component is custom then you can check `Controller` and `Controller Action` name in `rendering` ( /sitecore/layout/Renderings) , `Sitecore.XA.Foundation` is a default component

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No Worries. As an option I would recommend:

1. install fresh Sitecore 8.2 separately, you can download Sitecore
   8.2 from here https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82.aspx,
   it also provides an exe installer (Sitecore web application
   installer) that is very easy to use.
2. compare the following trees from existing and new Sitecore 8.2 instances: /sitecore/layouts/renderings/ and /sitecore/layouts/sublayouts/